# How to make path for gnu on windows

Tags: path, for-loop, window, gnustep

Just recently I installed the following programs on window 7 GNUstep msys, GNUstep core, GNUstep devel, GNUstep backend to learn objective C.

I wrote a piece of code just to print “Hello world” and saved it in a folder called “objectivec”  with .m extension (first.m). 
Then in the shell cmd window i changed the directory to objectivec by typing cd c:/objectivec
then to compile it I typed gcc –o first first.m  after the dollar ($)sign but it keeps showing me
gcc.exe No such file or directory
gcc.exe No input files
Should I create a path first either in user variable or System variable in enviroment variables? If so will you please tell me what should i do to solve the problem.
Thanks

Comment: You must use command in sh.exe

Answer (score 1):

First you should use the MSYS shell installed with the GNUstep packages.
The cmd window will not work as far as I know.

Second I would suggest to use GNUstep Makefiles to compile your code.
Invoking the compiler manually is usually error prone.

A Tutorial on how to write these Makefiles can be found [here](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/index.html) for example.